# Fatal Exception when using Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, floating-action-button

A Fragment from my Navigation drawer contains two RelativeLayouts that are supposed to act as buttons to navigate to two different Activities.
This is the code for that layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="#B3E5FC"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/existingClientChoiceLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
        android:text="Existing Client"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/newClientChoiceLayout"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/light_red">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
        android:text="New Client"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

  </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

In the layout of the Activity am supposed to navigate to from `existingClientChoiceLayout`, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_new_client"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="judeochalifu.teylur.activities.NewClientActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="14dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The (relevant) Fragment code looks like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_entry_layout, container, false);
    existingClientChoiceLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.existingClientChoiceLayout);
    newClientChoiceLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newClientChoiceLayout);

    existingClientChoiceLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ExistingClientsViewActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    newClientChoiceLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(mContext, NewClientActivity.class));
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Now, when I run the code everything looks fine.When I click on the option for this Fragment from the navigation menu, I get the WEIRD error message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: judeochalifu.teylur, PID: 4746
              java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
                  at judeochalifu.teylur.fragments.NewEntryFragment.onCreateView(NewEntryFragment.java:47)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Application terminated.
```

However, if I delete the FAB, everything works fine.

I've searched for related questions with similar titles, but none matches my specific problem.

Comment: If you dont need fab button, delete it, but if you need it, declare it. Then check if fab is not null, and if not add click listener to it.

Comment: Please title each of the sample code sections with their filenames. It isn't immediately obvious where the FAB XML is used, for example.

Comment: can u show the line which contains in 
onCreateView(NewEntryFragment.java:47)

Comment: It's missing ending tag `</relativelayout>` at first snipet code (i suppose you just forgot to add it over here). The error says that you're trying to cast a `textview`into `RelativeLayout`. Have you tried to put the `OnClickListener` into the button instead the `View`?

Comment: Clean project and rebuild again

Comment: this code does not cause this error. clean and rebuild, or make sure you are posting the correct error trace.

Comment: Thanks guys, cleaning and rebuilding was all I had to do.Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem, This is how I fixed:

1. **Clean Project** (from the Build menu)
2. **Rebuild Project** (from the Build menu)